# I get an Error "Load cannot follow more than 20 redirects" after installing ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, certbot, flask

this is my config file:

```
server {
        server_name songreccs.com;


        location /static {
                root /home/user/sonreccs/flaskrec/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/songreccs.com/fullchain.pem; # manage>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/songreccs.com/privkey.pem; # mana>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = songreccs.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name songreccs.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.songreccs.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        server_name www.songreccs.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/songreccs.com/fullchain.pem; # manage>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/songreccs.com/privkey.pem; # mana>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

before installing the certificate it was working. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Gunicorn. Gunicorn is running a flask app in the background.

Comment: Have you updated the site URL in your application so that it starts with `https`?

Comment: hey! thanks for the comment! I reinstalled the certificates a couple of times and it somehow works now! However the static files aren't loading anymore. I copied the new file in the area above.
I tried to change things up with "root" and "alias" and the trailing "/"´s in the paths of the location file, because that caused some trouble before installing the ssl certificate, but none of it helped..
Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a question where I didn't knew what I was doing.

The config file had a serverblock that listened on port 443 and redirects to port 443, which most likely have been the issue.